# Вывод содержимого .ini файла средствами php

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток. Есть некий .ini файл в котором содержится большой массив информации о пользователях. Необходимо всю информацию находящуюся в файле в читабельном виде вывести (на каждого пользователя по строке) на страницу сайта. Затем добавить несколько условий (например: в одном из дополнительных полей, если один из параметров пользователя = от 0 до 2500, то вывести одно изображение, от 2501 до 5000 - другое и т.д.). Объяснил несколько криво =) Надеюсь поймете...

**Вот 2 записи из .ini файла:**

```
[76561198777556446 StatsObject]  
PlayerName=Puma  
PlayerIP=86.102.208.50:14079  
SelectedVeterancy=ServerPerksV3.SRVetSharpshooter  
DamageHealedStat=0  
WeldingPointsStat=2620  
ShotgunDamageStat=5159  
HeadshotKillsStat=68  
StalkerKillsStat=0  
BullpupDamageStat=0  
MeleeDamageStat=1859  
FlameThrowerDamageStat=0  
SelfHealsStat=0  
SoleSurvivorWavesStat=0  
CashDonatedStat=0  
FeedingKillsStat=0  
BurningCrossbowKillsStat=0  
GibbedFleshpoundsStat=1  
StalkersKilledWithExplosivesStat=0  
GibbedEnemiesStat=16  
BloatKillsStat=15  
SirenKillsStat=6  
KillsStat=298  
ExplosivesDamageStat=10406  
TotalZedTimeStat=135.000000

[76561200266252308 StatsObject]  
PlayerName=Arko74  
PlayerIP=81.20.166.175:54019  
SelectedVeterancy=ServerPerksV3.SRVetSupportSpec  
DamageHealedStat=1282  
WeldingPointsStat=22490  
ShotgunDamageStat=9086  
HeadshotKillsStat=944  
StalkerKillsStat=239  
BullpupDamageStat=321378  
MeleeDamageStat=12972  
FlameThrowerDamageStat=0  
SelfHealsStat=279  
SoleSurvivorWavesStat=9  
CashDonatedStat=3440  
FeedingKillsStat=0  
BurningCrossbowKillsStat=0  
GibbedFleshpoundsStat=0  
StalkersKilledWithExplosivesStat=35  
GibbedEnemiesStat=132  
BloatKillsStat=199  
SirenKillsStat=63  
KillsStat=4295  
ExplosivesDamageStat=59712  
TotalZedTimeStat=2199.000000
```

**Вот мой вариант решения:**

вот мой вариант решения, но результат довольно печальный...

```
<body bgcolor="#fff">
<?
$num_of_mes = 500; // количество сообщений на странице
$num_of_mes2 = 15000;
$i=-28;$i2=-7;$i3=-24;$i4=-25;$i5=-4;$i6=-5;$ii2=-7;
$messages_array = file("ServerPerksStat.ini", true);
$overall_output = $messages_array;

srand ((double) microtime() * 10000000);
echo "<table align=Left bgcolor=#fff cellpadding=8 cellspacing=0 border=1 style='font-size :10px'>";
echo "<tr><td>".Игрок."</td><td>".Убийств."</td><td>".Сварка."</td><td>".Медицина."</td><td>".Очки."</td><td>".Игровое_время."</td></tr>";  
for($m=0;$m<$num_of_mes;$m++)
{$i=$i+29;$i2=$i2+29;$i3=$i3+29;$i4=$i4+29;$i5=$i5+29;$i6=$i6+29;
if($num_of_mes==1)
  { 
    echo "<tr><td>".$overall_output[$i]."</td><td>".$messages_array[$i2]."</td><td>".$messages_array[$i3]."</td><td>".$messages_array[$i4]."</td><td>".$messages_array[$i5]."</td><td>".$messages_array[$i6]."</td></tr>";  
}
  else
  {
    echo "<tr><td>".$overall_output[$i]."</td><td>".$messages_array[$i2]."</td><td>".$messages_array[$i3]."</td><td>".$messages_array[$i4]."</td><td>".$messages_array[$i5]."</td><td>".$messages_array[$i6]."</td></tr>";  
}
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Пробовал сделать все через функцию parse_ini_file(), но как-то безуспешно... 
Помогите разобраться

Answer (score 5):

Ппц вы тут трактористы.

```
$data = parse_ini_file($filename, true);
foreach($data as $key => $item)
...
```

Надеюсь, суть ясна и что надо дальше.

Тут кода в нацать раз меньше надо, чем вы накарявили.

Comment: На минуту опоздал =)

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach (parse_ini_file("ServerPerksStat.ini", true) as $id => $statsObject) {
    // выводим $statsObject['PlayerName'], $statsObject['PlayerIP'], etc
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<? header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf8')?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body><?
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$path = 'myfile.ini'; // наш файл
$objlist = array();
$ini_content = file_get_contents($path); // берем содержимое
$n = 0;
foreach(explode("\n", $ini_content) as $line) {  // разбиваем на линии
  if (empty($objlist[$n])) $objlist[$n] = new stdClass(); // если еще не создали, создаем объект
  if (trim($line) == '') { $n++; continue; } // если линяя пустая - пошел след. объект
  if ($line{0} == '[') { // если первый символ "[", значит, это заголовок
    list($num) = explode(' ', substr($line, 1), 2);
    $objlist[$n]->NUM = $num;
    continue;
    }
   // в других случаях пишем в объект пары ключ->значение
  if (strpos($line, '=') < 1) continue;
  @list($code, $val) = explode('=', $line, 2);
  $objlist[$n]->$code = $val;
  }

// начинаем вывод
// допустим, выводим Имя, Урон с Шотгана и хедшоты
echo '<table width="100%">';
echo '<tr><td>Имя</td><td>Урон с Шотгана</td><td>Хедшоты</td></tr>';
foreach ($objlist as $playerStats) {
  // а тут у вас объект $playerStats, с которым уже можно делать что угодно
  // выводим нужные поля
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td>'.$playerStats->PlayerName.'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$playerStats->ShotgunDamageStat.'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$playerStats->HeadshotKillsStat.'</td>';
  echo '</tr>';
  }
echo '</table>';
// конец вывода
?>
<pre>
Структура объекта:

<? var_dump($objlist[1]); ?>
</pre></body></html>
```

На всякий случай прикрепляю [файл](http://www.sh4dow.ru/test.rar). У меня ошибок не было.

Comment: спасибо за ответ! но если взять в расчет уже готовую наработку, что в ней необходимо исправить?

Comment: Я, если честно, ваш вариант уже позже увидел и просто так бы его не понял) Обновлю ща ответ, сделаю примерный вывод, а вы там уже смотрите но аналогии. Вот так вот. Собственно, вам осталось только путь к файлу указать в первой строке.

Comment: спасибо! 
используя предоставленный Вами код, получил ошибку: http://depositfiles.com/files/fxapy5p42
вот строки в которых есть ошибка:
15:  list($code, $val) = explode('=', $line, 2);
16:  $objlist[$n]->{$code} = $val;

Comment: добавил error_reporting(0), при запуске страницы получаю следующую ошибку:  
( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\www\index.php on line 3

3: $path = 'ServerPerksStat.ini'; // наш файл

Comment: Обновил ответ

Answer (score 2):

хм, не вижу проблем с [parse_ini_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php). У данной функции есть второй не обязательный параметр `$process_sections`, выставив которой в true вы получите ассоциативный массив секций ini файла:

```
array(2) {
    ["76561198777556446 StatsObject"]=>
    array(24) {
        ["PlayerName"]=> string(4) "Puma"
        ["PlayerIP"]=> string(19) "86.102.208.50:14079"
        ...
    }
    ["76561200266252308 StatsObject"]=>
    array(24) {
        ["PlayerName"]=> string(6) "Arko74"
        ["PlayerIP"]=> string(19) "81.20.166.175:54019"
        ...
    }
}
```

Затем не хитрыми телодвижениями выводим:

```
// начинаем вывод
// допустим, выводим Имя, Урон с Шотгана и хедшоты
echo '<table width="100%">';
echo '<tr><td>Имя</td><td>Урон с Шотгана</td><td>Хедшоты</td></tr>';

// ServerPerksStat.ini - это путь до твоего ini-файла
foreach(parse_ini_file('ServerPerksStat.ini', true, INI_SCANNER_RAW) as $key => $playerStats) 
{
    list($playerStats['NUM'], ) = explode(' ', $key);

    // выводим нужные поля
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$playerStats['PlayerName'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$playerStats['ShotgunDamageStat'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$playerStats['HeadshotKillsStat'].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
// конец вывода
```

UPD. Да простит меня [[@Sh4dow](/users/465/sh4dow)](/users/465/sh4dow), взял его кусок кода для вывода.
Какие поля выводить, думаю, сам решишь, ключи ассоциативного массива $playerStats, как видишь, совпадают с именами полей из ini-файла.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но не могли бы привести полный работающий пример на основе существующего кода, либо того, что предлагаете Вы ? Дело в том, что в php я профан...

Comment: оставив в файле только Ваш код из последнего блока и указав имя файла получил следующие ошибки при попытка открыть страницу: http://depositfiles.com/files/lekazbcra

Comment: покажите этот самый ServerPerksStat.ini похоже это какой-то не правильный ini фаил

Comment: вот он: http://depositfiles.com/files/t1tdxfvnq

Comment: Внес изменения, попробуйте еще раз - должно работать

Comment: Простит) Я увидел в INI строчку типа PlayerName=[CLAN].NAME, кажется parse_ini считает "[CLAN]" ссылкой на несуществующую группу. Собственно я такое предполагал и потому решал "в лоб" через explode. Вот и оно:<pre>PlayerName=[KFNOVA].steff</pre>

Comment: к сожалению, это не играет никакой роли (в RAW режиме, он парсит все после знака равно и до конца строки), у меня, почему-то даже самый банальный ini фаил сыпется с тойже ошибкой...пока не могу понять что не так :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059834/php-parse-ini-file-tc-constant-warning имхо, что-то типа этого. Вообще не люблю я я этот parse_ini_file, если в файлах ковыряние руками не подразумевается - лучше в serialized хранить.

Answer (score 1):

файлы index.php и ServerPerksStat.ini находятся в одной директории. 
Содержимое файла index.php:

```
 <?php
    // начинаем вывод
    // допустим, выводим Имя, Урон с Шотгана и хедшоты
    echo '<table width="100%">';
    echo '<tr><td>Имя</td><td>Урон с Шотгана</td><td>Хедшоты</td></tr>';

    // ServerPerksStat.ini - это путь до твоего ini-файла
    foreach(parse_ini_file('ServerPerksStat.ini', true, INI_SCANNER_RAW) as $key => $playerStats) 
    {
        list($playerStats['NUM'], ) = explode(' ', $key);

        // выводим нужные поля
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$playerStats['PlayerName'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$playerStats['ShotgunDamageStat'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$playerStats['HeadshotKillsStat'].'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
    // конец вывода
    ?>
```

Обращаясь браузером на эту страницу имеем следующие ошибки:

> Warning: syntax error, unexpected
> TC_LABEL, expecting '=' in
> ServerPerksStat.ini on line 1 in
> C:Program Files
> (x86)VertrigoServwwwstatindex.php
> on line 8
> Warning: Invalid argument
> supplied for foreach() in C:Program
> Files
> (x86)VertrigoServwwwstatindex.php
> on line 8

Код восьмой строки: `foreach(parse_ini_file('ServerPerksStat.ini', true, INI_SCANNER_RAW) as $key => $playerStats)`

Как все выгдит в браузере: http://rghost.ru/12961351

Comment: спасибо всем за помощь!
Но в итоге все равно ничего не работает =) Больше идей реализации не у кого нет?